# findOne not working in mongoose/node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This question is to do with the mongoose module for the NodeJS platform.

When I run the below, how do I get to the response from the DB?:

```
router.get('/profileSettings', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    databaseUserModel.findOne({'profileID':req.session.facebookProfileId}, function(err, userFromDB) {
        if(userFromDB){
            done(null, userFromDB);
        } else {
            console.log('Result does not exist');
       }
    });

    res.render('profileSettings', {title:siteName + ': Profile Settings', user:userFromDB});
})
```

It doesn't seem to work for me as userFromDB doesn't seem to exist - both in the findOne and also in the res.render methods! (undefined to be precise)

My databaseUserModel looks like this:

```
var databaseUser = new mongoose.Schema({
   profileID:String,
   fullname:String,
   profilePic:String,
   email:String,
   birthday:String,
   location:String,
   about:String
});

var databaseUserModel = mongoose.model('databaseUser', databaseUser);
```

The error message is:

```
ReferenceError: userFromDB is not defined
at Object.handle (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/routes/routes.js:75:84)
at next_layer (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Object.securePages [as handle] (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/routes/routes.js:20:13)
at next_layer (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
at /Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:205:24
at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:269:12)
at next (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:199:19)
at next (/Users/shayan/Repos/imo/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:38)
```

I feel it maybe something very simple I may be missing but I am just getting my hands dirty on NodeJS (and actually developing as a whole). I was coding in a niche language for my company before (they have developed it) so please bear with me.

Any input will help guys! I am really stuck on this

PS: my mongoose object works as I have used it to store data.

Comment: would be helpful if you could post the error msg :)

Comment: well of course! :) - added mate. Noob mistake

Comment: Also the find method gives you this error?

Comment: have you tried adding logging in to display err or userFromDB.  For example: 
            console.log(err);
            console.log(userFromDB); before if (userFromDB){

Comment: Yeah I gave them all a go. It's finally fixed by the way. See my response to the guy with the approved answer below. Thanks all! The community here is great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use result data only inside mongoose query i.e. you cannot use value return from `userFromDB` outside of `findOne`. Put your `res.render` inside it will solve.

```
router.get('/profileSettings', securePages, function(req, res, next){
    databaseUserModel.findOne({'profileID':req.session.facebookProfileId}, function(err, userFromDB) {
        if(userFromDB){
            res.render('profileSettings', {title:siteName + ': Profile Settings', user:userFromDB});
        } else {
            console.log('Result does not exist');
       }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks mate - that was one of the main issues! The other issue with this was with the databaseUserModel as the collections in the DB was called 'user'. What a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, we miss the await keyword before findOne which results in inappropriate results.

My Code before

```
let allUser = User.find({});
```

And all my business logic failed as I haven't retrieved it

My code after await

```
let allUser = await User.find({});
```

Now it retrieves the data correctly and my code works.

This is a mistake which I did and I thought findOne wasn't working. Hope it helps people to refrain from such mistakes.